# FadeOut entire div after deleting post with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to `.fadeOut()` a div after its content has been deleted from the database. This div and its content is `echo` via `PHP`.

Below is `echo` php code

```
echo '<form action="deletepost.php" method="post" enctype="nultipart/form-data">
  <div class="postSlate">
    <input style="display: none" type="submit" name="deletepost" id="deletepost" value="Delete">
    <label for="deletepost"><i class="typcn typcn-delete clsup2"></i></label>
    <input type="text" style="display: none" name="reqid" id="reqid" value="'.$req_id.'">
</form>
<ul class="slateDetails">
  <a href="userprofile.php?userid='.$post_id.'">
    <li><img class="exdetails" src="'.$profimages.'"></li>
    <li>'.$cname.'</li>
  </a>
</ul>
<div class="slateImg"><img src="'.$commodityimg.'"></div>
<div class="slateTitle extitle">
  <p>'.$req_title.'</p>
</div>
<div class="slateBrief">
  <p>'.$req_brief.'</p>
</div>
<div class="slateBtn">  </div>
</div>'
```

I use `AJAX` to execute the `deletepost.php`. Below is `ajax` code

```
$("#deletepost").click(function() {
      //e.preventDefault();
      reqid=$("#reqid").val();
      //userid=$("#userid").val();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "deletepost.php",
        data: "reqid="+reqid,
        success: function(html){
          if (html == 'true')
          {
              alert("Post Deleted");
              $('#deletepost').find('.postSlate').fadeOut();
          }
          else
          {
              alert("nothing");

          }
          //if (html == 'false')
          //{
            //  $(".logresult").html('<div class="loginDanger"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>   There was an error upgrading this account!. Please try again later.</div>');
          //}
        },
        beforeSend:function()
        {
          $(".logresult").html("<img src='images/ring.gif'>");
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
```

From code you'd see i have tried to use the `.find()` funtion to `.fadeOut()` the `div` carrying that particular post and this doesn't work but the post is deleted from databse so it's not a `PHP` issue. Please what's the solution to this?

Comment: Please correct `nultipart` to `multipart`

Answer (score 0):

The `find` method will try to find items **inside** the selector in context. In your case, the `$("#deletepost")` selector will return the jQuery element for the input element with id `deletepost` and it does not have any inner content.  The `postSlate` is a parent container div of `deletepost`. So use  any methods which can get you the outer container.

Here is how you use the `closest` method.

```
$('#deletepost').closest('div.postSlate').fadeOut();
```

Another option is `parent` method. But use parent when you are absolutely sure the item is your immediate parent. `closest()` will traverse outwards until it finds a match.

Also, but make sure you are not having **unique Ids** for each element. If you are rendering multiple posts inside a loop, you can use a css selector to wire up your `click` event and use relative selector methods (like `closest` and `find` as needed)

Comment: when i do this, say i have 5 post (12345) and i delete the 4th one (4), the first post (1) would be the one to fadeOut. Is there a fix?

Comment: That means you have `duplicate Id`s for elements in the document. Read my last paragraph. You should not be using ids for the jQuery code. Use relative selectors. See this working fiddle and make your code looks like that (not using Ids, but using relative selectors) http://jsbin.com/suqimadexi/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

Since the `id` attribute should be unique in the same document try to change the duplicate one by common classes, so `#deletepost` should be `.deletepost` :

```
<input style="display: none" type="submit" name="deletepost" id="deletepost" value="Delete">
```

Will be :

```
<input style="display: none" type="submit" name="deletepost" class="deletepost" value="Delete">
```

Should be `parent` instead :

```
$('#deletepost').parent('.postSlate').fadeOut();
```

So your selector will go up to the parent, Since `#deletepost` is a child of `.postSlate`.

Comment: when i do this, say i have 5 post (12345) and i delete the 4th one (4), the first post (1) would be the one to fadeOut. Is there a fix?

Comment: Yes, you must use the classes instead of id's `#deletepost`.